# Best practice for "recycling" rows on PostgreSQL (UPDATE vs INSERT + DELETE)

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, rdbms

I searched responses on "UPDATE vs INSERT + DELETE" in general terms and the consensus is UPDATE is faster, as expected.

My question is centered on a somewhat niche use case. Let's say you have a table of fairly high-frequency ephemeral data. For example, modelling notifications on a social network, those are created very often and you always see the latest N.

Would it make sense to keep the latest N (say 20) and when one comes in, the Nth row is UPDATED into the new one (ID included). Rather than inserting a new one and then trimming old rows (maybe in bulk on an interval)?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Or possibly, why even consider a database for this? Something like an in memory cache, queue etc seems better suited to such a low number of notifications with such a transient existence

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is MVCC. Every write produces a new row-version irrespective of whether the operation is insert or update. So I would not expect the proposed ring buffer style to give performance benefits.

With single-value systems, and fixed length rows I would expect faster performance. I'd like to see some thorough testing before I believed it was worthwhile, though.

Comment: Postgres has had HOT updates which (in some cases) makes a difference. [Hot Updates](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/) But I agree, in the specific case where it seems they are updating the whole row, that feature wouldn't matter.

Comment: It might be worth testing it, **with no indexes at all** in the table (so no PK or UNIQUE constraints either)

Answer (score -1):

The question of performance between an `UPDATE` statement or a similar `INSERT` and `DELETE` statement is too broad of a question to say which one is *faster*. It'll depend on the specific query used in both cases among other factors such as the schema structure and architecture, including how the table is indexed.

To address your specific example, I'm going to assume you're actually referring to the feed, e.g. the `StatusFeed` in Facebook, which is only the top N items, and is very ephemeral i.e. it changes on every refresh of the page (since I consider `Notifications` not very ephemeral and always expect the same `Notifications` to be waiting for me to view, regardless of how many times I refresh the page).

In such an example a traditional **RDBMS** could be used, like PostgreSQL, but might be a little overly architected of a choice for something that doesn't require much persistence. As Caius Jard points out, you would likely be better suited to use something designed for high-frequency and low-persistence like an in-memory solution, or possibly even a document data store since the schema is simple and there's not much relational logic needed to support such a use case.

If you were still fixed on (for the theory of it) trying to implement this with a traditional **RDBMS** then you'll likely generate less transactions and therefor have some slightly less overhead by doing only `UPDATES` as opposed to `INSERTS` and `DELETES`. But again, as far as which methodology will be *faster* overall or cause the least amount of contention, will very much dependent on how the schema is architected.

Comment: I don't I conveyed the example clearly enough to you. I didn't mean the (news)feed but rather notifications you see in the "bell" section. Like a list of:
- 3 people liked your post
- New message in a group you are in

Stuff like that. It's not THAT ephemeral, for some you might keep those 2 forever but most of the time, they last maybe some days or a week.
Also, even if you'd use an in-memory store as a cache, you generally have to keep the in a reliable storage, it might not be data you can re-create if needed

Comment: @ArielFlesler I can only reference existing systems like Facebook which `notifications` are not ephemeral, and the count of notifications will persist *forever* until you actually view them. If your system hides unviewed `notifications` after a specific timeframe, then I still consider them non-ephemeral and would use a table to store those data points, with the date when they're logged. You can use a View or the application itself to implement the logic of what to show and hide by comparing the difference of the current DateTime - the logged date of the `notification` to the timeframe you...

Comment: ...decide is the cutoff. Either way, that use case is not ephemeral, and should be persisted in a table for a multitude of reasons. Then the business logic can be applied on top of it as I just mentioned. So I would never `UPDATE` an old `notification` in such a system, only continue to `INSERT` new ones. I also wouldn't `DELETE` old ones (unless the user explicitly deletes it in the application). There's no need to worry about a table with more than 20 rows, nor a table with more than 10,000,000 rows from a performance perspective. But eventually you might decide on an archival process...

Comment: ...to move *old* data (perhaps over a year old) outside of the main table, to make **management** (DDL querying, not performance of DQL queries) of the main table easier. Sorry I misunderstood you, because the context of the `newsFeed` is an example of ephemeral data that you could use an in-memory solution (or one of the other solutions I mentioned) for without worrying about persisting it on reliable storage,